# Define a Sentinel node for a template class, a class which has no default constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, skip-lists

I have a requirement where I have to create a sentinel node of a template class. Which needs reference to itself

```
template <class T1, class T2>
class Node{
   private:
      std::pair<T1, T2> _pair;
      Node * next;
   public:
      Node(std::pair<T1, T2> pair) : _pair(pair){}
};

class Product{
  private:
    int pid;
    std::string name;
  public:
    Product(int id, std::string name):pid(id), name(name){}
}
```

Now I want to do something like

```
Node<Product, int> *base = new Node<Product, int>(/*which needs an arguement*/);
```

And I don't have to pass one, it gives me that default constructor is not available.

I need to for creating a skip list. Which needs boundary sentinels.

Comment: Normally that is achieved by having a node that is set to `nullptr`.  then you just check if the node equals `nullptr` and if it does then you have reached the end.

Comment: So, what exactly is your question?  It is true that the code above does not compile.  I can explain why, but you seem to know.  You have described something you cannot do, but you haven't described what it is what you want to do is supposed to do.  Why do you want a Sentinal node, and what properties does it need to have?  Why do you think you need it?

Comment: @Yakk I need to define a stl container, which is based on skip lists

Comment: @AAA The STL is an ancient library.  You mean a `std` style container?  Why would that justify using a Sentinal node?

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your problem correctly, it seems like all you have to do is define default constructors?

```
#include <string>
#include <utility>

template <class T1, class T2>
class Node{
private:
  std::pair<T1, T2> _pair;
  Node * next;
public:
  Node() {} // EDIT
  Node(std::pair<T1, T2> pair) : _pair(pair){}
};

class Product{
private:
  int pid;
  std::string name;
public:
  Product() {} // EDIT
  Product(int id, std::string name):pid(id), name(name){}
};

int main() {
  Node<Product, int> *base = new Node<Product, int>(/*which needs an arguement*/);
}
```

The above compiles and runs fine. Forgive me if I am oversimplifying.